# My data from axios doesn't save in my global variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, axios

I just wrote a function to fetch users from "reqres.in" with axios. I just cant save the data in my global variable but in the function with console.log everything is fine!
This is my code and thanks for your help

```
import "./style.css";
import axios from "axios";
let currentPage = 1;
let users = [];

// ***** Get Users from the Spisific Page *****
const getUsers = function (pageNumber) {
  const url = `https://reqres.in/api/users`;
  axios.get(url, { params: { pageNumber } }).then((res) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < res.data.data.length; i++) {
      users.push(res.data.data[i]);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Probably you try to read it before it was written. Remember this is asynchronous.

Comment: This is highly likely a [duplicate of this canonical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron), but it's hard to say for sure without seeing a bit more about how you're calling `getUsers` and subsequently accessing `users`.